# Which probability distribution to use

Tags: distributions

I'm looking to take random draws from a probability distribution and obtain right-skewed results where the mode falls around 0.2-0.3. So you can picture maybe a chi-square-*like* distribution shape between 0 and 1.

Which distribution has this quality so that I can take random draws in R and obtain the probabilities I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mode of a chi-squared distribution is $max(k-2, 0)$, where $k=$ the degrees of freedom, so you could use `rchisq()` with the `df` argument set to somewhere between 2.2 and 2.3. E.g., `rchisq(100, df=2.2)`.

If you need the random variable to be bounded between 0 and 1, you can use the beta distribution. The mode of the beta distribution is $\frac{\alpha - 1}{\alpha + \beta - 2}$ for $\alpha, \beta > 1$. So for you, one possible solution is $\alpha = 2$ and $\beta = 5$, which defines a beta distribution with mode = 0.2. In R you could do `rbeta(100, 2, 5)`, for example.

Comment: I think this is very helpful. I believe the code portion should be this: `pchisq(runif(100), df=2.2)` yea?

Comment: I doubt that is what you want. The solution I gave was sampling values from a chi-squared distribution with mode = 2.2 to 2.3. If you want to sample from a right-skewed distribution that is bound between 0 and 1, you'll probably want to use a beta distribution. I will edit my answer to provide a solution.

Comment: Yes, Beta is the one I want